# i need to visible and invisible the check box based on event date

Tags: android, android-layout, date, android-activity

I need to visible and invisible the check box based on the event date....I have 3 check boxes called on event day,2 days before,week before in my code....In add event,While adding the date itself it should calculate the intervals.. Based on the the intervals between current date and event date i need to change the visibility of check box..While for example if the interval is 2 days....i need to display only the event day and 2 days before check box....For this where i need to calculate the interval.where i need to add the code for check box....Please help me to find out the code...

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_occasion);

            context = getApplicationContext();

            seekBar_startTime = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
            seekBar_startTime.setProgress(0);
            seekBar_startTime.setMax(1440); //minutes in 24 hours(24*60)
            seekBar_startTime.setProgress(1);
            textView_startTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            seekBar_endTime = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
            seekBar_endTime.setProgress(0);
            seekBar_endTime.setMax(1440); //minutes in 24 hours(24*60)
            seekBar_endTime.setProgress(1);
            textView_endTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            btn_Date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.event_date_button);
            event_Place = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Enter_Place);
            custom_Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Custom_Text);
            checkBox_onEventDay=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_onEventDay);
            checkBox_2DaysBefore=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_2DaysBefore);
            checkBox_aWeekBefore=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_aWeekBefore);

            btn_create_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_button);
            sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);



            btn_Date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Occasion Date");
                    //Calendar eventDay = Calendar.getInstance();
 try {
                        String eventDate = btn_Date.getText().toString();
                        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
                        Date date1 = date.parse(eventDate);
                        DateFormat convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                        eventDate = convertDate.format(date1);
                        eventMO.setEventDate(eventDate);



                            Date currentDate = new Date();

                            long diff = date1.getTime()-currentDate.getTime();
                            long seconds = diff / 1000;
                            long minutes = seconds / 60;
                            long hours = minutes / 60;
                            long daysBefore = hours / 24;
hours%=24;
                    } catch (ParseException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                        if (daysBefore >= 7) {
                            if ((daysBefore == 7 && hours > 9) != true) {
                                checkBox_aWeekBefore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            checkBox_2DaysBefore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            checkBox_onEventDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        else if (daysBefore >= 2) {
                            if ((daysBefore == 2 && hours > 9) != true) {
                                checkBox_aWeekBefore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                //checkBox_2DaysBefore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            //checkBox_onEventDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        else if (daysBefore >= 1) {
                            checkBox_aWeekBefore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            checkBox_2DaysBefore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            //checkBox_onEventDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        }


                    });
    /eventid get from OccasionFragment here
            Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {

                Long eventId1 = bundle.getLong("EventID");
                eventId2 = eventId1;
                String eventName = bundle.getString("EventName");
                custom_Text.setText(eventName);
                String eventPlace = bundle.getString("EventPlace");
                event_Place.setText(eventPlace);
                String eventDate = bundle.getString("EventDate");
                try {
                    //String eventDate = bundle.getString("EventDate");
                    //time string removed from date here
                    String result = eventDate.split(" ")[0];
                    DateFormat sourceDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    // parse the date string into Date object
                    Date date = sourceDate.parse(result);
                    DateFormat convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
                    // format the date into another format
                    result = convertDate.format(date);
                    btn_Date.setText(result);


                } catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Event Start Time and Event End Time string added before the time here
                String eventStart = bundle.getString("EventStart");
                textView_startTime.setText("Event Start Time :" + eventStart);
                String eventEnd = bundle.getString("EventEnd");
                textView_endTime.setText("Event End Time :" + eventEnd);

            }

            btn_create_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    doOnCLickAndOnOptionSelected();

                }
            });


        }

        @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
        public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
                return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            }

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                Date = new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append(" ").toString();
                btn_Date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(year).append(" ").toString());
            }
        }

    }
```

i tried this code inside the btn_date on click listener to calculate the interval at the time of adding the date...but it is not working....i need visible and invisible the at the time of adding the date itself..Please help me..

Add event consist of Event name,place,date,start time,end time...After this only i have 3 check boxes..Then save button to save the event

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: No error...But it is not working......

Comment: I don't know how is it possible....While adding date itself i need to calculate the intervals....For that where i need to add the codes.....Please tell me

Comment: did u see my answer?

Comment: Ya i saw that.....i tried your answer in btn_date...it is not working...I don't know what to do

Comment: why did u use in button date? where did u use the second code snippet?

Comment: second code snippet??...I don't know where to add...That is why i tried in btn_date......

Comment: where did u use this code                                                                           try{                                                                                                                String eventDate = btn_Date.getText().toString();                                              .........

Comment: please update your code.... Its not clear...

Comment: do you have global variable daysBefore,hours?....

Comment: remove the declarations of hours and daysBefore inside the try-catch

Comment: thank you for your reply

Comment: after adding the event...i have a option to update it later...While going to update event check box are visible and invisible based on the condition...while adding the event it is not functioning????

Comment: Now it works good...I pasted my code in date picker.....Thank your help arun

Answer (score 1):

Remove the declaration of hours, daysBefore...
use like this... that is the problem

```
  hours = minutes / 60;
  daysBefore = hours / 24;
```

you calculation is wrong, to get the remaining days.

```
diff = event_date - current_date

   long diff = date1.getTime() - currentDate.getTime() ;



      try {
                    String eventDate = btn_Date.getText().toString();
                    DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
                    Date date1 = date.parse(eventDate);
                    DateFormat convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                    eventDate = convertDate.format(date1);
                    eventMO.setEventDate(eventDate);



                        Date currentDate = new Date();
                        //This is remainder kind of app right
                        //long diff = currentDate.getTime() - date1.getTime();

                        //days_remaining - current
                        long diff = date1.getTime() - currentDate.getTime() ;
                        long seconds = diff / 1000;
                        long minutes = seconds / 60;
                        hours = minutes / 60;
                        daysBefore = hours / 24;

                      //you need get remaining hours
                       hours %= 24;

                   if (daysBefore >= 7) {
                        if ((daysBefore == 7 && hours > 9) != true) {
                            checkBox_aWeekBefore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        checkBox_2DaysBefore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        checkBox_onEventDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else if (daysBefore >= 2) {
                        if ((daysBefore == 2 && hours > 9) != true) {
                            checkBox_aWeekBefore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            //checkBox_2DaysBefore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        //checkBox_onEventDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else if (daysBefore >= 1) {
                        checkBox_aWeekBefore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        checkBox_2DaysBefore.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //checkBox_onEventDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }                    
                } catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```